# How to check if a word is a palindrome (Python)

Tags: python

Please help...
So the instruction says to program the computer to check whether a word is a palindrome or not. I inputted this code:

```
def is_palindrome(word):

counter_from_first_letter=0
counter_from_last_letter=-1

from_first_letter = word[counter_from_first_letter]
from_last_letter = word[counter_from_last_letter]

max_index_from_first= len(word)
max_index_from_last= (len(word))*-1

while from_first_letter == from_last_letter:  
    from_first_letter = word[counter_from_first_letter]
    from_last_letter = word[counter_from_last_letter]

    counter_from_first_letter += 1
    counter_from_last_letter -= 1
    return True
```

The problem is the computer only checks whether the first and last letters are the same, and if they are, it just returns true. How do I make sure the computer checks every single letter? Thanks

Comment: The return is inside the loop? There is a lot wrong with this code, not just that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Bobby Um... if you're gonna give a critique, at least be accurate. The OP *did* give an example of what they tried. The issue is more of a "why is my code not working" combined with "help me with my homework assignment."

Comment: What will you do if the word is not a palindrome?  You never return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if word == word[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Maybe, since it's a class/homework assignment, just offer a possible hint in a comment instead of doing their homework for them? I don't even think the OP has learned the syntax you're using, considering the basic nature of their question and the code they wrote.

Comment: Also, what you posted is a completely different approach to the one they wrote. You basically posted your own solution, ignoring theirs.

Comment: Also, why `if perfectlyfineboolyoucouldjustreturn: return True else: return False`?

Answer (score 1):

in python-3

```
name = 'madam'
print(name.find(name[::-1]) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this: first convert your string into a list, then reverse the list and convert it back into a string. compare both the strings and if they match? they are palindromes, if not, they aren't.

```
'''checking whether a word is a palindrome
we first convert the word into a list then join it;
use an if statement to compare the two strings'''

def palindrome(string):#you need the input(string)
    palindrome_check=[]#create an empty list
    for character in string [::-1]:#create a list from the input
        #(use a for loop because you now know the range)
        #the [::-1] analyzes the characters in reverse 
        palindrome_check.append(character)#add each character to the new empty list
    #print(palindrome_check)
    rev_string= ''.join(palindrome_check)#.join -creates a string from the created list
    print(rev_string)
    #REMOVE SPECIAL CHARACTERS- IM THINKING OF A LOOPING THROUGH, BUT NOT SURE HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT
    string=string.replace(' ', '')
    rev_string=rev_string.replace(' ', '')
    string=string.replace(',', '')
    rev_string=rev_string.replace(',', '')
    string=string.replace('.', '')
    rev_string=rev_string.replace('.', '')
    #THIS IS THE LOGIC: IT CHECKS BOTH STRINGS, if they are equal, it is a palindrome; 
    if string.lower()==rev_string.lower():
        return True, print('It is a Palindrome')
    else:
        return False, print('It isnt a palindrome')

#call the function; key in the parameters- 
palindrome= palindrome("No, Mel Gibson Is A Casinos Big Lemon")
#maybe we can try having a user key in the parameter? lets try
#palindrome=palindrome(input('kindly enter your word/phrase  '))-wrong
#print('Kindly enter your word or phrase')
#user_palindrome=input('')
#palindrome=palindrome(user_palindrome)
#it wont work this way either
```

If you can have the user define the parameter(string), the better, if you know how to do this, kindly share.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a word or phrase is a palindrome, it be necessary to check if the original sentence is equal to the original sentence reversed.

```
word = "Eva can I see bees in a cave"

word_lower = word.lower().replace(" ", "")

if word_lower == word_lower[::-1]:
    print("It's a palindrome")
else:
    print("This is not a palindrome")
```